# Why local class can access const local variables of enclosing function?

Tags: c++

I recently discovered that local class cannot access Auto variables of enclosing function as they might contain invalid reference to local variable. For Example

```
struct Helper {
    virtual int getLocal() = 0;
};

Helper* nutshell(){
    int local = 123;
    struct Internal : public Helper {
        int i = INT16_MAX; // Unnecessary
        int getLocal(){ return local; }
    };
    return new Internal();
};
```

The above code is disaster because `getLocal` has invalid reference to `local`. A solution for this could be making `local` static or enum, But what's interesting for me is that making it a const is also a possible way.

```
struct Helper {
    virtual int getLocal() = 0;
};

Helper* nutshell(){
    const int local = 123;
    struct Internal : public Helper {
        int i = INT16_MAX; // Unnecessary
        int getLocal(){ return local; }
    };
    return new Internal();
};
```

My question is why is that, Why local class can access const variable?

Isn't a `const` qualified variable a Auto variable?

Comment: "Isn't a `const` qualified variable a Auto variable?" - Answer: No it isn't.

Comment: @paladin So, const variable doesn't has automatic storage duration?

Comment: This depends on the compiler and the code. (Many compiler try to "optimize" `const` "variables", aka getting rid of them entirely.)

Comment: perhaps this description helps you to understand it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859643/which-memory-area-is-a-const-object-in-in-c

Comment: Because `const` is, err, `const`, so actually the compiler can copy the value into the local class, without having to worry about the enclosing stack frame disappearing. It can't do that with variables.